# MYSQL complex query in 5 million rows and errors with 1317

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have table with 5 million rows.
Example

```
+----+-----------+---------+-------
|  product    | date       |  count    | 
+-------------+------------+-----------+
|  платье     | 04-01-2024 | 186574    | 
|  штаны      | 04-01-2024 | 20564     |
|  кепка      | 07-01-2024 | 104443    | 
|  штаны      | 06-01-2024 | 10574     | 
|  платье     | 06-01-2024 | 223001    |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

I need select rows with 2 custom date,then if product name1 = name2  get the difference between count and then get top 100 on this diffence.

now i create 2 select and then I'm looping through the array to get it. but i have error about memory. How can i create 1 query in mysql ?

my query

```
    $get_ex = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE date = :date");
    $get_ex->execute(array(':date' => $first_date));
    $ex_list_2 = $get_ex->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    
    $get_ex_3 = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE date = :date");
    $get_ex_3->execute(array(':date' => $second_date));
    $ex_list_3 = $get_ex_3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    
    $result = Array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($ex_list_2 as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach($ex_list_3 as $key2 => $value2)
        {
            if($value['product_name'] == $value2['product_name'])
            {
                $result[$i]['product_name'] = $value['product_name'];
                $result[$i]['count_1'] = $value['count'];
                $result[$i]['count_2'] = $value2['count'];
                $result[$i]['res'] = $value['count']- $value2['count'];
                $i++;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

and result -

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

memory_limit = 2048mb

for result i need array with next info

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  product    | 04-01-2024  |  06-01-2024 |  diff     | 
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  платье     | 186574      | 223001      | 36427     |
|  штаны      | 20564       | 10574       | 99000     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

not working with order by and have error 1317 in mysql

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, use English language sample data. And provide a complete [mcve], i.e. also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: `fetchall` will always run into a memory issue if you have many rows, best to do all calculations and comparisons in mysql if possible

Comment: 1 select - 1 million rows, I do example and expected result. Dont know how do it in mysql query.

Comment: In the above data set, should you be selecting both `штаны` rows then subtracting the counts? Please provide example of what you have, and what you want.

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE product` (Which is the DDL of this table).  I think you are missing an index...

Answer (score 4):

Don't do two queries, use a single `JOIN` query.

```
SELECT t1.product_name, t1.count AS count1, t2.count AS count2, t1.count - t2.count AS res
FROM product AS t1
JOIN product AS t2 ON t1.product_name = t2.product_name
WHERE t1.date = :first_date AND t2.date = :second_date
ORDER BY res DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: *`AND t2.date = :second_date` (I believe)

Comment: And `ORDER BY difference DESC LIMIT 100` at the end.

Comment: how can i order by diffrence if i dont now it. I calculate them if different dates and names coincide

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your query and avoid memory issues, you can use a single SQL query to perform all the necessary operations. This is to join the table with itself on the product name, filter the rows by the two specific dates, calculate the difference in counts, and then order the results to get the top 100 differences.

Here is the revised version of your SQL query that could work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.product,
    t1.count AS date1,
    t2.count AS date2,
    t2.count - t1.count AS diff
FROM 
    product AS t1
JOIN 
    product AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product
WHERE 
    t1.date = '2024-01-04' AND 
    t2.date = '2024-01-06'
ORDER BY 
    ABS(diff) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Here's an example PHP code to apply the new SQL query:

```
$first_date = '2024-01-04';  // Set your first date
$second_date = '2024-01-06'; // Set your second date

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        t1.product,
        t1.count AS date1,
        t2.count AS date2,
        t2.count - t1.count AS diff
    FROM 
        product AS t1
    JOIN 
        product AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product
    WHERE 
        t1.date = :first_date AND 
        t2.date = :second_date
    ORDER BY 
        ABS(diff) DESC
    LIMIT 100";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':first_date', $first_date);
$stmt->bindParam(':second_date', $second_date);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[image]

Comment: thank yoy to, you helo me understand calculations in query

Comment: one more question if i have "-10000" in diff. how can i *(-1) in query?

Comment: In the new query that I shared, ABS(t1.count - t2.count) provides positive number only which is absolute difference. If you want to get the numbers as is even though it's negative, just remove ABS function.
Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But if i add "ORDER BY diff DESC" array empty

Comment: You can then use ABS() function in Order By like below.
SELECT 
    t1.product,
    t1.count AS count_date1,
    t2.count AS count_date2,
    t1.count - t2.count AS diff
FROM 
    product AS t1
JOIN 
    product AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product
WHERE 
    t1.date = '2024-01-04' AND 
    t2.date = '2024-01-06'
ORDER BY 
    ABS(diff) DESC
LIMIT 100;

Comment: I try . No error and empty array . If i delete order by diff desc - its okay. i get 100 rows, if i add order by - empty array - with abs or without

Comment: In your database, are there any rows that have NULL value in count column?
If so, diff value also can get NULL value and it causes Order By diff not working properly.

Comment: In that case, you will need to handle NULL values for count columns. Try this way.

SELECT 
    t1.product,
    t1.count AS count_date1,
    t2.count AS count_date2,
    COALESCE(t1.count, 0) - COALESCE(t2.count, 0) AS diff
FROM 
    product AS t1
JOIN 
    product AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product
WHERE 
    t1.date = '2024-01-04' AND 
    t2.date = '2024-01-06'
ORDER BY 
    ABS(diff) DESC

Comment: yes. count1 - count2 can be 0. so diff can be 0

Comment: Example with COALESCE didnot work to. i try in WHERE t1.date = '2024-01-04' AND t2.date = '2024-01-06' AND diff > 0 ... not work too

Comment: If i limit 10000 or limit 1000 with out order BY .. array empty too ( without errors

Comment: I don't understand why. It should work. I've just adjusted my answer a bit, but basically it's same. In my testing by creating some sample table (like what you shared in your original question), the SQL query worked as expected.

Comment: What database are you working with? (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) and are you testing through your PHP codes or on SQL DB directly?

Comment: Mysql and try it on sql query. add screenshot im my main query

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Do3N.png

Comment: @Ростислав: You are storing dates as integers? Why? And in your query you are using the same date twice, so the difference will always be zero.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: date in unixtime in db.  oh yes, but if i enter diffrent days - 1317 error to