# Mysql and phpmyadmin 1317 error in result query on order by

Tags: mysql

This question is continuation of [MYSQL complex query in 5 million rows and errors with 1317](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77783031/mysql-complex-query-in-5-million-rows-and-errors-with-1317).

In the main table we have 2 million rows.

This code works fine:

```
SELECT 
    t1.product, t1.count AS count_date1, t2.count AS count_date2, 
    COALESCE(t1.count, 0) - COALESCE(t2.count, 0) AS diff 
FROM  
    product AS t1 
JOIN 
    product AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product 
WHERE 
    t1.date = '2024-01-04' 
    AND t2.date = '2024-01-06' 
LIMIT 100
```

But if I add `ORDER BY` or click on column diff in result table in phpmyadmin - I get an error 1317 (don't worry in name (key_name) I rename columns) or if I have limit > 100. error 1317

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LujsU.png)

I try to check if null, try to limit 10 with order by - nothink help.

[Query execution was interrupted, error #1317](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354229/query-execution-was-interrupted-error-1317) this questions - dont help me.

[full error with query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQCF.png)

[db_res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfKmf.png)

Comment: WHICH EXACT query gives you this error?

Comment: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**is work**' at line 1"   ??

Comment: WHICH EXACT query gives you this error? - if i click on diff column in mysql or this query

SELECT t1.key_name, t1.count AS count_date1, t2.count AS count_date2б , COALESCE(t1.count, 0) - COALESCE(t2.count, 0) AS diff FROM key_2_csv AS t1 JOIN key_2_csv AS t2 ON t1.key_name = t2.key_name WHERE t1.date = '1704315600' AND t2.date = '1704488400' ORDER BY ABS(diff) DESC
LIMIT 100

Comment: count_date2б its - wrong   count_date2 - correct

Comment: Please add the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE product (Which is the DDL of this table). I think you are missing an index...

Comment: Please make your problem clear by providing a [mre].  With current info i cannot see a problem (besides missing indexes), see: https://dbfiddle.uk/GXQezfd7

Comment: i add minimum of info.. code and error, now i add full screenshots in my questons
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQCF.png 1 and second https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfKmf.png - this tables creates from csv file and will have - 10-20-40 million rows

Comment: Please read: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) (and screenshorts in Russian (?) are not helpfull anywayz)

Comment: early i add full info.. u want more... i send it..

Comment: i add sreenshots for example to see the problem

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL code seems generally fine, but one thing to note is that you're using column aliases `(count_date1, count_date2, and diff)` in the SELECT clause, and you should use them in the ORDER BY clause if you're ordering the results based on these columns.